# How to get Android button graphic changes to show immediately?

Tags: android, button, graphics, background

I am trying to get a button to fade out when a particular event occurs, but the changes to the button are not instantaneous but instead wait for all the operations on the button performed to complete.Is there any (hopefully, simple) way to show the changes to the user as they occur?

CODE:

```
featuredimage.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.featuredimage_cc_movement1));
            for (int alpha = 0; alpha < 255; alpha+=10) {
                //Thread.sleep(1);
                featuredimage.setAlpha(alpha);
                featuredinfo.setAlpha(alpha);
            }

            featuredinfo.setText(Html.fromHtml("<center><big><b>FEATURED " + catagory + "</b></big></center><br>" 
                    + getFeatured().getMediumString()));
            featuredimage.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.featuredimage_gradient));

            for (int alpha = 255; alpha > 0; alpha--) {
                //Thread.sleep(1);
                featuredimage.setAlpha(alpha);
                featuredinfo.setAlpha(alpha);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is use AsyncTask found [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why just do not use the selector and button states? if event occurs just simply assign the particular state to the button. Button in this particular state will have a different image background.

Comment: Well the current setup for the fade requires changing the alpha from 0 to 255 in increments of 10, which would require 25 states for a single button, each individually called for each element that is effected by the change. So unless there is another solution then it seems like a lot of excessive code.

Comment: It seems I have missunderstood your question. I will remove it.